# Not able to get TermVector results properly in SolrNet

Tags: solrnet

I'm not able to get TermVector results properly thru SolrNet. I tried with the following code.

```
QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions()
{
    OrderBy = new[] { new SortOrder("markupId", Order.ASC) },
    TermVector = new TermVectorParameters
    {
        Fields = new[] { "text" },
        Options = TermVectorParameterOptions.All
    }
};

var results = SolrMarkupCore.Query(query, options);

foreach (var docVectorResult in results.TermVectorResults)
{
    foreach (var vectorResult in docVectorResult.TermVector)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(vectorResult.ToString());
}
```

In the above code, results.TermVectorResults in the outer foreach gives the proper count whereas docVectorResult.TermVector in the inner foreach is empty.

I've copied the generated solr query of the above code and issued against solr admin and I'm properly getting the termVectors values. The actual query I issued is below

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?sort=markupId+asc&tv.tf=true&start=0&q=markupId:%2823%29&tv.offsets=true&tv=true&tv.positions=true&tv.fl=text&version=2.2&rows=50
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet

Comment: Cross-posted: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/-VWZGSFlI8I/Y4WhTtuUalMJ

Answer (score 0):

First you should check HTTP query to sure termvector feature is set property.

If it's not OK, change your indexing based on:

[The Term Vector Component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-term-vector-component.html)

If it is OK,You can use "ExtraParams" by changing the handler to termvector handler. Try this:

```html
public SolrQueryExecuter<Product> instance { get; private set; }

 public ICollection<TermVectorDocumentResult> resultDoc(string q)
            {
                string SERVER="http://localhost:7080/solr/core";//change this
                var container = ServiceLocator.Current as SolrNet.Utils.Container;
                instance = new SolrQueryExecuter<Product>(
                   container.GetInstance<ISolrAbstractResponseParser<Product>>(),
                   new SolrConnection(SERVER),
                   container.GetInstance<ISolrQuerySerializer>(),
                   container.GetInstance<ISolrFacetQuerySerializer>(),
                   container.GetInstance<ISolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParser<Product>>());
                instance.DefaultHandler = "/tvrh";
                SolrQueryResults<Product> results =
                    instance.Execute(new SolrQuery(q),
                new QueryOptions
                {
                    Fields = new[] { "*" },
                    Start = 0,
                    Rows = 10,
                    ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                        { "tv.tf", "false" },
                        { "tv.df", "false" },
                        { "tv.positions", "true" },
                        { "tv", "true" },
                        { "tv.offsets", "false" },
                        { "tv.payloads", "true" },
                        { "tv.fl", "message" },// change the field name here
                    }
                }
                );
                return results.TermVectorResults;
            }
```